Shouldn't the 'core' tag be immediately deleted?
I just saw a question with the 'core' tag.
When searching core there were 2 questions:
Shouldn't the tag be deleted at once?
(Apparently this tag has already been deleted in the past, but has come up again).
It seems to be used instead of asp.net-core or simply .net.

Funnily, I see this, i.e. 1 question is somehow tagged, but it doesn't show up. This may be a case of the bug (was brought up some time agon on meta) that prevents the tag from being automatically deleted.

@Lino I just removed the tags from those questions. So "1 question" might be just a caching artifact. I'd wait a day or two to see if the tag is auto-deleted.

"Shouldn't it be deleted at once?" - you forgot to explain why you think this requires immediate action. Because this kind of reads like you are seeing this as more of a problem than it actually is.

@Gimby: See the answer below: "it took many month of work for several curators to clean up the mess". So I am not the only one seeing this as a problem.

@Gimby it is self evident. What does core means and it is on topic for SO? The answer to that is that is ambiguous and ambiguous topics needs to be expressed unambiguously by a single tag.

Yes, whenever you see a question tagged with core, please remove the
core tag and retag the question to the correct tag.
The tag was created yesterday again and I deleted it from that question, but last night someone used it again, so it could not be deleted by the system.
Unused tags are only cleaned up once a day, so only if at that time there is no question, the tag will be deleted from the system.
The tag existed in the past and peaked at about 2.5k questions and it took many months of work for several curators to clean up the mess. So far I haven't seen a single question that needed the tag.
Examples of wrong tagging from the past, that also show how ambiguous the tag is, are:

[.net][core], which should be [.net-core] (same for all Microsoft technologies like ASP.NET, Entity Framework, etc.
[core][dump] -> [coredump]
[core][cpu] -> [cpu-cores]
["whatever product"][core] -> ["whatever product"-core] (if tag available), otherwise just remove [core]
[php][core] -> just [php]
[java][core] -> just [java]

Btw. due to caching you might see such effects as the one illustrated by @Lino's screenshot. Click on the different tabs (Newest, Active, etc.) and see how the number even changes.
Update:
The tag is gone now, it was deleted by the cleanup process last night.
This was at least the second time the tag reappeared after its first cleanup (January '24). To avoid this in the future it should be considered to blocklist the tag so that it can't be created again.

"it took many month of work for several curators to clean up the mess". That's why I posted this.

@PoulBak and that's why I answered it ;) I was one of the several curators and retagged or close voted hundreds of [core]-questions. As the tag was created yesterday and still survived until today, we have to make sure that every time it comes up it gets deleted from the question ASAP. Then hopefully by tomorrow it will be gone.

It seems like black-listing the tag would be appropriate.
